# Set positional parameters using command substitution

Tags: bash, parameters

I would like to set the positional parameters using command substitution. This works fine for a simple case

```sh
$ set $(echo hello; echo world)

$ echo $1
hello
```

However if a "line" contains a space then it will fail

```sh
$ set $(echo hello hello; echo world world)

$ echo $1
hello
```

I also tried changing `IFS` value

```sh
$ IFS=$'\n' set $(echo hello hello; echo world world)

$ echo $1
hello
```

Comment: can you use a subshell ? `(IFS=$'\n'; set .... )`

Comment: @suspectus: Yours worked because of the semicolon after `IFS=$'\n'` -- that makes it set IFS for the entire shell, not just for the `set` command.

Comment: Awesome question! Was looking on how to achieve something extremely similar, without IFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IFS=$'\n' set $(echo hello hello; echo world world)` is almost right, but not quite: it runs the `set` command with IFS set to newline, but that happens after the output of `$( ... )` has already been parsed using the standard value of IFS. You need to set IFS as a separate command, *then* use the `set` command, then set IFS back:

```
$ saveIFS=$IFS
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ set $(echo hello hello; echo world world)
$ IFS=$saveIFS
$ echo "$1"
hello hello
echo "$2"
world world
```